# React state update on object

Tags: reactjs

If I have the following Person object in state

```
this.state = {
    Person: {
        FirstName: "John",
        LastName: "Doe"
    }
}
```

Is it valid do the following...?

```
this.state.Person.FirstName = "Jane"
```

If not, why?

Comment: Use `setState`. You need to make react aware that the state has changed, and you do that by calling that method.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's not recommended to assign `this.state` directly elsewhere than the `constructor`. You should always use the `setState` `API` to update the state.

Your answer is, it's valid to do so, but the right way is to use `this.setState`.

In your case you should update the first name as bellow:

```
let person = this.state.Person;
this.setState({
    Person: {
        ...person,
        FirstName: "Jane"
    }
})
```

Comment: Why is my way valid but not recommended?

Comment: For eg if I have an edit popup with 2 fields that allow me to edit the first and last name, should i be able to do state.Person.FirstName/LastName? and in the Save button click function i pass the this.state.Person to a prop function or something..?

Comment: If you change state directly it won't invoke the lifecycle methods and other staffs. read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the way state is managed and how the data flows to the component.

The correct way to update state is using:

```
this.setState({...})
```

You can read more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Answer (score 0):

You should use component's setState with `this.setState` like this

```
this.setState(state => ({
  Person: {
    ...state.Person,
    FirstName: 'Jane'
  }
}))
```

With that, you keep the state immutable and correctly rerendered. Directly changing the state is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

@ZeroDarkThirty

Your way is obviously valid but not recommended. Why:

- According to React's convention, **states are immutable**(don't change
  the original state object). So whenever you want to make changes, you
  should add something to it instead of changing it completely.
- And, states are way to re-render your components with the new data. **So, 
  React's 
  setState() method updates your state and on update of state, the components get 
  re-rendered.**

  ```
  this.setState(state => ({
     Person: {
      ...state.Person,
      FirstName: 'Jane'
     }
  }))
  ```